# problem with passing dynamic path parameter to a component function

Tags: django, django-views

[views:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJ5RN.png)

*I use this function as a render partial

[urls:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEm2F.png)

URL:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/cat/lundury/

I should be able to get the cat parameter which is a path parameter with passing it to the function.

but I get this error:

> TypeError at /products/cat/lundury/
> Product_tags_component() missing 1 required positional argument: 'cat'

I will be really thankful if any one helps me.